# Grep find directory but root cant view it

Tags: ubuntu, grep

Why grep can find a folder, but root cant nor view file in this folder nor cd this folder?

this is terminal output using `grep -rh "addons27" /`

[image]

I trying to find releases directory in OpenErp 6.0.4 server

Comment: Where are you seeing the grep find from? What is the full context of the python errors? Is python erroring out because that file doesn't exist?

Comment: this is terminal output using  `grep -rh "addons27" /`

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code. That way, you can remove anything you don't want to show us and we can still understand what you do show.

Comment: What file are the python errors coming from? They aren't explicitly saying that the file exists, it looks like it could potentially just be a file that contains python errors. Please provide surrounding context in text form

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's impossible to answer "why can `grep` find a folder?" because this question contains a false premise. You're seeing the content of some file(s), not paths to files examined by `grep`. Your grep found text that looks like a path. The actual path to the file examined by grep was not printed; you would see it if you didn't use `-h`.

> `-h`, `--no-filename`
> **Suppress** the prefixing of file names on output. This is the default when there is only one file (or only standard input) to search.

<sup>(source: [`man 1 grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/grep.1.html), emphasis mine)</sup>

The answer to "why can't root view files in this folder nor `cd` to this folder?" is in the error message you got: there is no such directory. Maybe such directory used to be; or maybe it was (is) in another computer (where the file examined by `grep` originates from).

Example:

```
$ echo '/nonexistent/path something' > file1
$ echo '/another/fake/path whatever' > file2
$ 
$ grep -h path file1 file2
/nonexistent/path something
/another/fake/path whatever
$ 
$ grep path file1 file2
file1:/nonexistent/path something
file2:/another/fake/path whatever
$
```

`file1` and `file2` are paths to existing files. `/nonexistent/path` and `/another/fake/path` are just strings found in the files. They look like paths but this does not mean the paths exist in the file hierarchy.